# Inserting a NOP in FORTRAN

Tags: assembly, fortran, gfortran, fortran90, inline-assembly

In `C`, I would use `asm ("nop");` for inserting an inline `NOP` instruction. However, I couldn't find a way to do it with `FORTRAN`.

Is there any way of forcing a compiler to emit a `NOP`? I use gfortran.

The reason behind this is that my MPI program segfaults on calling `MPI_Finalize` and doesn't, when I insert a `print *, ''` or a `sleep(1)` just before `MPI_Finalize`. To further isolate this behavior, I want to insert a `NOP` before the call and see if segfault still happens.

***Edit:*** I am not sure why there are downvotes and close requests for this question. On further search, this question is similar to [Segmentation fault during MPI_FINALIZE() in Fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564951/segmentation-fault-during-mpi-finalize-in-fortran)

Comment: Have you tried compiling and running with all the run time checks turned on, i.e. -fcheck=all? You'll probably want -g as well. The behaviour you describe is often due to you writing to some memory you shouldn't and the checks may help you find such an occurence - though in MPI codes it's not guaranteed.

Comment: @IanBush I use -fcheck=all and -ggdb by default. The compilation is clean.

Comment: Yeah, I should have done that. However, I still don't understand how `sleep` or `print` can completely avoid the segfault.

Comment: It can fix it because it changes the layout of the program in memory in such a way as to stop you trashing something that immediately causes an error, and instead has probably had some much more subtle and insidious effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the `segfault` is due to my assumption that `IERR` in `MPI_Finalize(IERR)` is an optional parameter. When I supply a parameter, it doesn't crash anymore.

To inline `NOP`, I wrote a `C` function and used `BIND C` in fortran to make an interface.

**C function**

```
void noop(long n)
{
    while (--n > 0)
        __asm__("nop");
}
```

**FORTRAN interface**

```
interface
    subroutine nop_inline(n) bind(c, name="noop")
        use ISO_C_BINDING, only: c_long
        implicit none
        integer (c_long), value :: n
    end subroutine nop_inline
end interface
```

It is still weird how `printf` or `sleep` was able to prevent the `segfault` but calling `NOP` for `1E8` times didn't.

I am happy to accept any explanation for this behavior as an answer.

Comment: @High Performance Mark What a coincidence! I saw your comment on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564951/segmentation-fault-during-mpi-finalize-in-fortran and replaced all includes with `use mpi`. Thank you.

Comment: Just a very far fetched guess... maybe printf/sleep leaves some garbage on stack, which works as valid argument for finalize.